# Qt. Как подключить свои же статические библиотеки под линукс?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Писал проект под линукс на Eclipse C++. Наконец-то решил перейти на Qt Creator.

Создал проекты для своих статических библиотек, всё компилируется замечательно.

Теперь создаю приложение. Подключают библиотеки, но ничего выдаёт ошибку "undefined reference ..."

Что может быть не так?

Comment: Могу предположить, что при сборки приложения Вы не указали , что ваши библиотеки нужно присоединить к проекту.

Comment: Прописал INCLUDEPATH и LIBS. Что ещё нужно указать?

Comment: Покажите pro-файл и ошибку.